# How can I make the "count" keep increasing without the "count" starting 0 again

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am still new to Studio Android and connecting with Firebase.

I have several pages on the app and trying to collect any typed information through Firebase.

```
public class faculty_last_respond extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

 private Button submitBtn;

 private DatabaseReference fbRef;
 private int count = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 finalQ = new lastQuestion();


 fbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FacultyResponse/User " + count);


 fbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
     if(snapshot.exists())
      count += 1;
 }


submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

 String inputTextQ2 = textQ2.getText().toString();
 finalQ = new lastQuestion(buttonTextQ1, inputTextQ2, buttonTextQ3, buttonTextQ4, buttonTextQ5);

 fbRef.push().setValue(finalQ); 
 
 lastPage();
 }
 });

}
```

I am trying to store every data under the path "FacultyResponse/User " + count.
(Ex. User0, User1, User2, etc)

Firebase Sample of collecting data under User 0 only

[image]

But as seen in the screenshot, the data is still being in under User 0.

I am not quite sure why "count" is not being increased by 1.

I hope I asked the question clearly.

Comment: Using sequentially incremental counters like that is an antipattern in Firebase's Realtime Database. See [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only setting `fbRef` once, and not updating it when you increment `count`.

```
 fbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FacultyResponse/User " + count);


 fbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
     if(snapshot.exists()) {
       count += 1;
       dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FacultyResponse/User " + count);
     }
 }
```

But, as commented, sequentially incrementing counters like this are an antipattern in Firebase, and I recommend reading the blog post [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). Instead of arrays, use Firebase's built-in `push()` operation to generate auto-incrementing (but non-sequential) keys.

Using that, you end up with this much more idiomatic code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FacultyResponse").push().setValue(finalQ);
```

Comment: Hi, I really appreciated your help and suggested reading a useful blog. If you didn't mention that I need to update "fbRef," I might be stuck with it.